# Swagger produces no documentation for REALLY simple application

Tags: java, rest, swagger, resteasy, swagger-2.0

I've been banging my head against this for several days, so hopefully someone can help out with this simple problem.

I've been following various guides to get RESTEasy working in Java, and attaching Swagger to it to auto produce documentation. I've now finally managed to get everything up and running, but Swagger doesn't produce any documentation apart from the default inbuilt stuff, and I can't figure out for the life of me what I'm missing.

I've broken the application up into a single package, with two classes.

SimpleEndpoint.java

```
package SwaggerAndRESTEasy;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;

import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse;


@Api(value="My First RESTEASY Endpoint")
@Path("/simpleendpoint")
public class SimpleEndpoint 
{

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@ApiOperation(value = "Returns a nice little message")
@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "yay", response = SimpleEndpoint.class)
public String getTest() {
    return "Hello REST World!";
}

@GET
@Path("/users/{id}")
@Produces("application/json")
@ApiOperation(value = "Returns a nice little message")    
public String returnID(@PathParam("id") Integer id)
{
    return id + "";
}
}
```

Init.java

```
package SwaggerAndRESTEasy;

import io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class Init extends Application 
{
public Init() 
{

    BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
    beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.0");
    beanConfig.setContact("Mario");
    beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
    beanConfig.setHost("localhost");
    beanConfig.setBasePath("/api");
    //beanConfig.setResourcePackage("io.swagger.resources");
beanConfig.setResourcePackage("SimpleEndpoint.class.getPackage().getName()");
    beanConfig.setScan(true);
    beanConfig.setPrettyPrint(true);

}    


@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() 
{
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet();

    resources.add(SimpleEndpoint.class);

    //Swagger Resources
    resources.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
    resources.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);

    return resources;
}  

}
```

Swagger Output

```
{
   "swagger":"2.0",
   "info":{
      "version":"1.0.0",
      "contact":{
         "name":"Mario"
      }
   },
   "host":"localhost",
   "basePath":"/api",
   "schemes":[
      "http"
   ]
}
```

Can someone point me in the direction of what I'm doing wrong?